# css column-count with divs and textarea

Tags: html, css

Here is the fiddle, can someone get this so that the text area can be displayed inline with the other columns?

https://jsfiddle.net/ckatocnz/

Example of the fiddle html below

```
<div class="row">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div><textarea>3</textarea></div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You definitely need to apply `display: inline-block;` to your child divs inside `.row`.

```css
.row div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.row textarea {
  box-sizing: border-box; 
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div><textarea>3</textarea></div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```css
.row {
 border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
 border-spacing: 2px;
 border-style: outset outset outset outset;
 border-color: black black black black;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 -webkit-column-count: 5; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 5; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 5;
}

.row textarea {
  height: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div><textarea>3</textarea></div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
</div>
```